# website for jobs in applied or industrial mathematics (or financial math)

Tags: career, advice

What are the websites for general position in applied or industrial mathematics(or financial mathematics) related jobs (that is if we have to find a non academic job temporarily) ?Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For finance, I recommend wilmott.com and gloriamundi.org. There's also www.mathjobs.org.

Comment: You might also end up looking at MO in a while, depending on the advertising situation...